# Print multiple Primefaces Chart.js

Tags: java, printing, primefaces, export, chart.js

I want to print multiple p:pieChart that generate inside a p:repeat so I do not know how many charts there are.I just want to get a PDF with all the charts basically. I have tried using this:

```
<p:printer target="@([id$=divWhereAllTheChartsAre]) " />
```

But the charts appear blank. I also saw this in the official documentation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    function exportChart() {
        //export image
        $('#output').empty().append(PF('chart').exportAsImage());

        //show the dialog
        PF('dlg').show();
    }
//]]>
</script>
```

But I cannot get the component by its PF widgetVar because there are more than one. Is there any other way to export the charts?

I am working with the primefaces7.0.jar, thanks.

Comment: @Kukeltje Hmmm and then I can just iterate over the different widgetVars, thanks. I don't know why I didn't think of that earlier, using a bean property with a correlative to name the widgets. And the upvotes appeared like 5 minutes after I posted this, I also thought is was kind of weird haha.

Comment: Please remove the edit and creste an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, I used a bean property to name each component using a counter. After this, I could just reference each one using a loop.

Bean:

```
private int widgetCounter= 0;
public String generateWidgetVar() {
    return "chart" + (this.widgetCorrelativo++);
}
```

XHTML:

```
<p:pieChart widgetVar="#{cargarReporteBean.generateWidgetVar()}"
```

Comment: Uhhhh.... why not use the index from the repeat and add that to a fixed string?